# how to live a live application screen having camera view with some other UIViews over Camera view

Tags: ios, swift, live-streaming, avcapturesession, screensharing

Actually, I want to broadcast a live match with some overlays over it like sponsors images on top corners of the screen and a score card on the bottom of the screen. Can someone help me or guide me on a way of implementation I use this pod (haishinkit) but this pod is not serving the purpose. I use rtmpstream.attachScreen function for broadcasting my UIView but this function is not picking up my camera view (AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer) other than this scorecard and sponsor images are broadcasting. I want to broadcast my Camera Screen along with Scorecard, other images along with the audio.

```
import UIKit
import HaishinKit
import AVFoundation
import VideoToolbox
import Loaf
import WebKit


class BroadcastViewController: UIViewController, RTMPStreamDelegate {
    
    // Camera Preview View
    @IBOutlet private weak var previewView: UIView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var videoView: UIView!
    // Camera Selector
    @IBOutlet weak var cameraSelector: UISegmentedControl!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var webview: WKWebView!
    // Go Live Button
    @IBOutlet weak var startStopButton: UIButton!
    
    // FPS and Bitrate Labels
    @IBOutlet weak var fpsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var bitrateLabel: UILabel!
    
    // RTMP Connection & RTMP Stream
    private var rtmpConnection = RTMPConnection()
    private var rtmpStream: RTMPStream!

    // Default Camera
    private var defaultCamera: AVCaptureDevice.Position = .back
    
    // Flag indicates if we should be attempting to go live
    private var liveDesired = false
    
    // Reconnect attempt tracker
    private var reconnectAttempt = 0
    
    // The RTMP Stream key to broadcast to.
    public var streamKey: String!
    
    // The Preset to use
    public var preset: Preset!
    
    // A tracker of the last time we changed the bitrate in ABR
    private var lastBwChange = 0
    
    // The RTMP endpoint
    let rtmpEndpoint = "rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/"
    
    
    //Camera Capture requiered properties
        var videoDataOutput: AVCaptureVideoDataOutput!
        var videoDataOutputQueue: DispatchQueue!
        var previewLayer:AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
        var captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice!
        let session = AVCaptureSession()
    
    var isPublic = false

    // Some basic presets for live streaming
    enum Preset {
        case hd_1080p_30fps_5mbps
        case hd_720p_30fps_3mbps
        case sd_540p_30fps_2mbps
        case sd_360p_30fps_1mbps
    }
    
    // An encoding profile - width, height, framerate, video bitrate
    private class Profile {
        public var width : Int = 0
        public var height : Int = 0
        public var frameRate : Int = 0
        public var bitrate : Int = 0
        
        init(width: Int, height: Int, frameRate: Int, bitrate: Int) {
            self.width = width
            self.height = height
            self.frameRate = frameRate
            self.bitrate = bitrate
        }
    }
    
    // Converts a Preset to a Profile
    private func presetToProfile(preset: Preset) -> Profile {
        switch preset {
        case .hd_1080p_30fps_5mbps:
            return Profile(width: 1920, height: 1080, frameRate: 30, bitrate: 5000000)
        case .hd_720p_30fps_3mbps:
            return Profile(width: 1280, height: 720, frameRate: 30, bitrate: 3000000)
        case .sd_540p_30fps_2mbps:
            return Profile(width: 960, height: 540, frameRate: 30, bitrate: 2000000)
        case .sd_360p_30fps_1mbps:
            return Profile(width: 640, height: 360, frameRate: 30, bitrate: 1000000)
        }
    }

    // Configures the live stream
    private func configureStream(preset: Preset) {
        
        let profile = presetToProfile(preset: preset)
        
        // Configure the capture settings from the camera
        rtmpStream.captureSettings = [
            .sessionPreset: AVCaptureSession.Preset.hd1920x1080,
            .continuousAutofocus: true,
            .continuousExposure: true,
            .fps: profile.frameRate
        ]
        
        // Get the orientation of the app, and set the video orientation appropriately
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            if let orientation = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.windowScene?.interfaceOrientation {
//                let videoOrientation = DeviceUtil.videoOrientation(by: orientation)
                rtmpStream.orientation = .landscapeRight
                rtmpStream.videoSettings = [
                    .width: (orientation.isPortrait) ? profile.height : profile.width,
                    .height: (orientation.isPortrait) ? profile.width : profile.height,
                    .bitrate: profile.bitrate,
                    .profileLevel: kVTProfileLevel_H264_Main_AutoLevel,
                    .maxKeyFrameIntervalDuration: 2, // 2 seconds
                ]
            }
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
        
        // Configure the RTMP audio stream
//        rtmpStream.audioSettings = [
//            .bitrate: 128000 // Always use 128kbps
//        ]
    }
    
    
    // Publishes the live stream
    private func publishStream() {
        print("Calling publish()")
        rtmpStream.attachScreen(ScreenCaptureSession(viewToCapture: previewView))
        rtmpStream.publish("minestreamkey")
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.startStopButton.setTitle("Stop Streaming!", for: .normal)
        }
    }
    
    // Triggers and attempt to connect to an RTMP hostname
    private func connectRTMP() {
        print("Calling connect()")
        rtmpConnection.connect(rtmpEndpoint)
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
//        videoView.startSession()
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.setupAVCapture()
        previewView.bringSubviewToFront(webview)
        webview.load(NSURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://graphics.crickslab.com/scorecard/0865e840-f147-11eb-95cb-65228ef0512c/Blitzz-vs-Crickslab-Officials-Fri30Jul2021-1201AM-")! as URL) as URLRequest)
        print("Broadcast View Controller Init")
        
        print("Stream Key: " + "FB-3940543509404805-0-AbxeU6r48NpFcasH")
        
        // Work out the orientation of the device, and set this on the RTMP Stream
        rtmpStream = RTMPStream(connection: rtmpConnection)
        
        // Get the orientation of the app, and set the video orientation appropriately
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            if let orientation = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.windowScene?.interfaceOrientation {
                let videoOrientation = DeviceUtil.videoOrientation(by: orientation)
                rtmpStream.orientation = videoOrientation!
            }
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
        
        // And a listener for orientation changes
        // Note: Changing the orientation once the stream has been started will not change the orientation of the live stream, only the preview.
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(on(_:)), name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
        
        // Configure the encoder profile
        configureStream(preset: self.preset)
     
//         Attatch to the default audio device
//        rtmpStream.attachAudio(AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .audio)) { error in
//            print(error.description)
//        }
//
//        // Attatch to the default camera
//        rtmpStream.attachCamera(DeviceUtil.device(withPosition: defaultCamera)) { error in
//            print(error.description)
//        }

        // Register a tap gesture recogniser so we can use tap to focus
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
        previewView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        previewView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        // Attatch the preview view
//        previewView?.attachStream(rtmpStream)
        
        // Add event listeners for RTMP status changes and IO Errors
        rtmpConnection.addEventListener(.rtmpStatus, selector: #selector(rtmpStatusHandler), observer: self)
        rtmpConnection.addEventListener(.ioError, selector: #selector(rtmpErrorHandler), observer: self)
        
        rtmpStream.delegate = self
                
        startStopButton.setTitle("Go Live!", for: .normal)
    }
    
    //  Tap to focus / exposure
    @objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.ended {
            let point = sender.location(in: previewView)
            let pointOfInterest = CGPoint(x: point.x / previewView.bounds.size.width, y: point.y / previewView.bounds.size.height)
            rtmpStream.setPointOfInterest(pointOfInterest, exposure: pointOfInterest)
        }
    }

    // Triggered when the user tries to change camera
    @IBAction func changeCameraToggle(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        
        switch cameraSelector.selectedSegmentIndex
        {
        case 0:
            rtmpStream.attachCamera(DeviceUtil.device(withPosition: AVCaptureDevice.Position.back))
        case 1:
            rtmpStream.attachCamera(DeviceUtil.device(withPosition: AVCaptureDevice.Position.front))
        default:
            rtmpStream.attachCamera(DeviceUtil.device(withPosition: defaultCamera))
        }
    }
    
    // Triggered when the user taps the go live button
    @IBAction func goLiveButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        print("Go Live Button tapped!")
        
        if !liveDesired {
            
            if rtmpConnection.connected {
                // If we're already connected to the RTMP server, wr can just call publish() to start the stream
                publishStream()
            } else {
                // Otherwise, we need to setup the RTMP connection and wait for a callback before we can safely
                // call publish() to start the stream
                connectRTMP()
            }

            // Modify application state to streaming
            liveDesired = true
            startStopButton.setTitle("Connecting...", for: .normal)
        } else {
            // Unpublish the live stream
            rtmpStream.close()

            // Modify application state to idle
            liveDesired = false
            startStopButton.setTitle("Go Live!", for: .normal)
        }
    }
    
    // Called when the RTMPStream or RTMPConnection changes status
    @objc
    private func rtmpStatusHandler(_ notification: Notification) {
        print("RTMP Status Handler called.")
        
        let e = Event.from(notification)
                guard let data: ASObject = e.data as? ASObject, let code: String = data["code"] as? String else {
                    return
                }

        // Send a nicely styled notification about the RTMP Status
        var loafStyle = Loaf.State.info
        switch code {
        case RTMPConnection.Code.connectSuccess.rawValue, RTMPStream.Code.publishStart.rawValue, RTMPStream.Code.unpublishSuccess.rawValue:
            loafStyle = Loaf.State.success
        case RTMPConnection.Code.connectFailed.rawValue:
            loafStyle = Loaf.State.error
        case RTMPConnection.Code.connectClosed.rawValue:
            loafStyle = Loaf.State.warning
        default:
            break
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            Loaf("RTMP Status: " + code, state: loafStyle, location: .top,  sender: self).show(.short)
        }
        
        switch code {
        case RTMPConnection.Code.connectSuccess.rawValue:
            reconnectAttempt = 0
            if liveDesired {
                // Publish our stream to our stream key
                publishStream()
            }
        case RTMPConnection.Code.connectFailed.rawValue, RTMPConnection.Code.connectClosed.rawValue:
            print("RTMP Connection was not successful.")
            
            // Retry the connection if "live" is still the desired state
            if liveDesired {
                
                reconnectAttempt += 1
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.startStopButton.setTitle("Reconnect attempt " + String(self.reconnectAttempt) + " (Cancel)" , for: .normal)
                }
                // Retries the RTMP connection every 5 seconds
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
                    self.connectRTMP()
                }
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    // Called when there's an RTMP Error
    @objc
    private func rtmpErrorHandler(_ notification: Notification) {
        print("RTMP Error Handler called.")
    }
    
    // Called when the device changes rotation
    @objc
    private func on(_ notification: Notification) {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            if let orientation = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.windowScene?.interfaceOrientation {
                let videoOrientation = DeviceUtil.videoOrientation(by: orientation)
                rtmpStream.orientation = videoOrientation!
                
                // Do not change the outpur rotation if the stream has already started.
                if liveDesired == false {
                    let profile = presetToProfile(preset: self.preset)
                    rtmpStream.videoSettings = [
                        .width: (orientation.isPortrait) ? profile.height : profile.width,
                        .height: (orientation.isPortrait) ? profile.width : profile.height
                    ]
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    }
    
    // Button tapped to return to the configuration screen
    @IBAction func closeButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    // RTMPStreamDelegate callbacks
    
    func rtmpStreamDidClear(_ stream: RTMPStream) {
    }
    
    // Statistics callback
    func rtmpStream(_ stream: RTMPStream, didStatics connection: RTMPConnection) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.fpsLabel.text = String(stream.currentFPS) + " fps"
            self.bitrateLabel.text = String((connection.currentBytesOutPerSecond / 125)) + " kbps"
        }
    }
    
    // Insufficient bandwidth callback
    func rtmpStream(_ stream: RTMPStream, didPublishInsufficientBW connection: RTMPConnection) {
        print("ABR: didPublishInsufficientBW")
        
        // If we last changed bandwidth over 10 seconds ago
        if (Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970) - lastBwChange) > 5 {
            print("ABR: Will try to change bitrate")
            
            // Reduce bitrate by 30% every 10 seconds
            let b = Double(stream.videoSettings[.bitrate] as! UInt32) * Double(0.7)
            print("ABR: Proposed bandwidth: " + String(b))
            stream.videoSettings[.bitrate] = b
            lastBwChange = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                Loaf("Insuffient Bandwidth, changing video bandwidth to: " + String(b), state: Loaf.State.warning, location: .top,  sender: self).show(.short)
            }
            
        } else {
            print("ABR: Still giving grace time for last bandwidth change")
        }
    }
    
    // Today this example doesn't attempt to increase bandwidth to find a sweet spot.
    // An implementation might be to gently increase bandwidth by a few percent, but that's hard without getting into an aggressive cycle.
    func rtmpStream(_ stream: RTMPStream, didPublishSufficientBW connection: RTMPConnection) {
    }
}

// AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate protocol and related methods
extension BroadcastViewController:  AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate{
     func setupAVCapture(){
        session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.vga640x480
        guard let device = AVCaptureDevice
        .default(AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera,
                 for: .video,
                 position: AVCaptureDevice.Position.back) else {
                            return
        }
        captureDevice = device
        beginSession()
    }

    func beginSession(){
        var deviceInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput!

        do {
            deviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
            guard deviceInput != nil else {
                print("error: cant get deviceInput")
                return
            }

            if self.session.canAddInput(deviceInput){
                self.session.addInput(deviceInput)
            }

            videoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
            videoDataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames=true
            videoDataOutputQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "VideoDataOutputQueue")
            videoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue:self.videoDataOutputQueue)

            if session.canAddOutput(self.videoDataOutput){
                session.addOutput(self.videoDataOutput)
            }

            videoDataOutput.connection(with: .video)?.isEnabled = true

            previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.session)
            previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect

//            let rootLayer :CALayer = self.previewView.layer
            self.videoView.layer.masksToBounds=true
            previewLayer.frame = videoView.bounds
            videoView.layer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer)
            
            session.startRunning()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            deviceInput = nil
            print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        // do stuff here
        if let description = CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(sampleBuffer) {
            let dimensions = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(description)
            rtmpStream.videoSettings = [
                .width: dimensions.width,
                .height: dimensions.height ,
                .profileLevel: kVTProfileLevel_H264_Baseline_AutoLevel
            ]
        }
        rtmpStream.appendSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer, withType: .video)
        
    }

    // clean up AVCapture
    func stopCamera(){
        session.stopRunning()
    }

}
```

Comment: So, you want to add some overlays to your capture and broadcast that?
If so, you have to actually edit the frames.
Maybe see here for a starting point: https://www.raywenderlich.com/6236502-avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos

Comment: Can you please explain how Facebook RTMPS url setup into HaishinKit?

Comment: @ZahirulIslam there are 2 function in which we have to add 
 stream key and server url respectively.
rtmpStream!.publish("FBstreamkey") 
rtmpConnection.connect("FBServerurl")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to live stream camera view with overlays on it by creating 2 RTMPStream objects, one for attaching the camera and the second one is for attachscreen. following is the code.

```
import AVFoundation
import HaishinKit
import Photos
import UIKit
import VideoToolbox
import WebKit

final class ExampleRecorderDelegate: DefaultAVRecorderDelegate {
    static let `default` = ExampleRecorderDelegate()

    override func didFinishWriting(_ recorder: AVRecorder) {
        guard let writer: AVAssetWriter = recorder.writer else {
            return
        }
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({() -> Void in
            PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: writer.outputURL)
        }, completionHandler: { _, error -> Void in
            do {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: writer.outputURL)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        })
    }
}

final class LiveViewController: UIViewController {
    private static let maxRetryCount: Int = 5

    @IBOutlet private weak var lfView: MTHKView!
    @IBOutlet private weak var currentFPSLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private weak var publishButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet private weak var pauseButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet private weak var videoBitrateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private weak var videoBitrateSlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet private weak var audioBitrateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private weak var zoomSlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet private weak var audioBitrateSlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet private weak var fpsControl: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet private weak var effectSegmentControl: UISegmentedControl!

    @IBOutlet weak var webview: WKWebView!
    private var rtmpConnection = RTMPConnection()
    private var rtmpStream: RTMPStream!
    private var rtmpStreamLayer: RTMPStream!
    private var sharedObject: RTMPSharedObject!
    private var currentEffect: VideoEffect?
    private var currentPosition: AVCaptureDevice.Position = .back
    private var retryCount: Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        rtmpStream = RTMPStream(connection: rtmpConnection)
        rtmpStreamLayer = RTMPStream(connection: rtmpConnection)
        if let orientation = DeviceUtil.videoOrientation(by: UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation) {
            rtmpStream.orientation = orientation
        }
        rtmpStream.captureSettings = [
            .sessionPreset: AVCaptureSession.Preset.hd1280x720,
            .continuousAutofocus: true,
            .continuousExposure: true
            // .preferredVideoStabilizationMode: AVCaptureVideoStabilizationMode.auto
        ]
        rtmpStreamLayer.captureSettings = [
            .sessionPreset: AVCaptureSession.Preset.hd1280x720,
            .continuousAutofocus: true,
            .continuousExposure: true
            // .preferredVideoStabilizationMode: AVCaptureVideoStabilizationMode.auto
        ]
        rtmpStream.videoSettings = [
            .width: 720,
            .height: 1280
        ]
        rtmpStream.mixer.recorder.delegate = ExampleRecorderDelegate.shared
        
        rtmpStreamLayer.videoSettings = [
            .width: 720,
            .height: 1280
        ]
        rtmpStream.mixer.recorder.delegate = ExampleRecorderDelegate.shared

        videoBitrateSlider?.value = Float(RTMPStream.defaultVideoBitrate) / 1000
        audioBitrateSlider?.value = Float(RTMPStream.defaultAudioBitrate) / 1000

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(on(_:)), name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didEnterBackground(_:)), name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didBecomeActive(_:)), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        logger.info("viewWillAppear")
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        rtmpStream.attachAudio(AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .audio)) { error in
            logger.warn(error.description)
        }
        rtmpStream.attachScreen(ScreenCaptureSession(viewToCapture: view))
        rtmpStream.attachCamera(DeviceUtil.device(withPosition: currentPosition)) { error in
            logger.warn(error.description)
        }
        rtmpStreamLayer.attachScreen(ScreenCaptureSession(viewToCapture: view))
        rtmpStreamLayer.receiveAudio = false
        
        rtmpStream.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "currentFPS", options: .new, context: nil)
        lfView?.attachStream(rtmpStream)
        lfView?.attachStream(rtmpStreamLayer)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        logger.info("viewWillDisappear")
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        rtmpStream.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "currentFPS")
        rtmpStream.close()
        rtmpStream.dispose()
    }

    @IBAction func rotateCamera(_ sender: UIButton) {
        logger.info("rotateCamera")
        let position: AVCaptureDevice.Position = currentPosition == .back ? .front : .back
        rtmpStream.captureSettings[.isVideoMirrored] = position == .front
        rtmpStream.attachCamera(DeviceUtil.device(withPosition: position)) { error in
            logger.warn(error.description)
        }
        currentPosition = position
    }

    @IBAction func toggleTorch(_ sender: UIButton) {
        rtmpStream.torch.toggle()
    }

    @IBAction func on(slider: UISlider) {
        if slider == audioBitrateSlider {
            audioBitrateLabel?.text = "audio \(Int(slider.value))/kbps"
            rtmpStream.audioSettings[.bitrate] = slider.value * 1000
        }
        if slider == videoBitrateSlider {
            videoBitrateLabel?.text = "video \(Int(slider.value))/kbps"
            rtmpStream.videoSettings[.bitrate] = slider.value * 1000
        }
        if slider == zoomSlider {
            rtmpStream.setZoomFactor(CGFloat(slider.value), ramping: true, withRate: 5.0)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func on(pause: UIButton) {
        rtmpStream.paused.toggle()
    }

    @IBAction func on(close: UIButton) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func on(publish: UIButton) {
        if publish.isSelected {
            UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = false
            rtmpConnection.close()
            rtmpConnection.removeEventListener(.rtmpStatus, selector: #selector(rtmpStatusHandler), observer: self)
            rtmpConnection.removeEventListener(.ioError, selector: #selector(rtmpErrorHandler), observer: self)
            publish.setTitle("●", for: [])
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
            rtmpConnection.addEventListener(.rtmpStatus, selector: #selector(rtmpStatusHandler), observer: self)
            rtmpConnection.addEventListener(.ioError, selector: #selector(rtmpErrorHandler), observer: self)
            rtmpConnection.connect(Preference.defaultInstance.uri!)
            publish.setTitle("■", for: [])
        }
        publish.isSelected.toggle()
    }

    @objc
    private func rtmpStatusHandler(_ notification: Notification) {
        let e = Event.from(notification)
        guard let data: ASObject = e.data as? ASObject, let code: String = data["code"] as? String else {
            return
        }
        logger.info(code)
        switch code {
        case RTMPConnection.Code.connectSuccess.rawValue:
            retryCount = 0
            
            rtmpStream!.publish("yourstreamkey")
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2)
            {
                self.rtmpStreamLayer!.publish("yourstreamkey")
                  }
            
            // sharedObject!.connect(rtmpConnection)
        case RTMPConnection.Code.connectFailed.rawValue, RTMPConnection.Code.connectClosed.rawValue:
            guard retryCount <= LiveViewController.maxRetryCount else {
                return
            }
            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: pow(2.0, Double(retryCount)))
            rtmpConnection.connect(Preference.defaultInstance.uri!)
            retryCount += 1
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    @objc
    private func rtmpErrorHandler(_ notification: Notification) {
        logger.error(notification)
        rtmpConnection.connect(Preference.defaultInstance.uri!)
    }

    func tapScreen(_ gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        if let gestureView = gesture.view, gesture.state == .ended {
            let touchPoint: CGPoint = gesture.location(in: gestureView)
            let pointOfInterest = CGPoint(x: touchPoint.x / gestureView.bounds.size.width, y: touchPoint.y / gestureView.bounds.size.height)
            print("pointOfInterest: \(pointOfInterest)")
            rtmpStream.setPointOfInterest(pointOfInterest, exposure: pointOfInterest)
        }
    }

    @IBAction private func onFPSValueChanged(_ segment: UISegmentedControl) {
        switch segment.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            rtmpStream.captureSettings[.fps] = 15.0
        case 1:
            rtmpStream.captureSettings[.fps] = 30.0
        case 2:
            rtmpStream.captureSettings[.fps] = 60.0
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    @IBAction private func onEffectValueChanged(_ segment: UISegmentedControl) {
        if let currentEffect: VideoEffect = currentEffect {
            _ = rtmpStream.unregisterVideoEffect(currentEffect)
        }
        switch segment.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 1:
            currentEffect = MonochromeEffect()
            _ = rtmpStream.registerVideoEffect(currentEffect!)
        case 2:
            currentEffect = PronamaEffect()
            _ = rtmpStream.registerVideoEffect(currentEffect!)
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    @objc
    private func on(_ notification: Notification) {
        guard let orientation = DeviceUtil.videoOrientation(by: UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation) else {
            return
        }
        rtmpStream.orientation = orientation
    }

    @objc
    private func didEnterBackground(_ notification: Notification) {
        // rtmpStream.receiveVideo = false
    }

    @objc
    private func didBecomeActive(_ notification: Notification) {
        // rtmpStream.receiveVideo = true
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey: Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if Thread.isMainThread {
            currentFPSLabel?.text = "\(rtmpStream.currentFPS)"
        }
    }
}
extension LiveViewController : UIWebViewDelegate
{
    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
      
        webview.scrollView.zoomScale = 10
    }
}
```